# Azure Media Player not working on Android Chrome(network,server failed/Format not supported)

Tags: android, azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to play the azure media player sample from [here](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_setsource.html)(Basic unprotected content), however the player gives me the error:

> The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network
>   failed or because the format is not supported (0x20300000)

**Additional Information:**
Application version: Chrome 52.0.2743.98

Operating system: Android 4.2.1 HUAWEI G610-U20

From the logs:

> I/chromium(23174): [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[16:25:29.869]  error: videojs:
>   (CODE:540016640 undefined)  object Object
>   http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.4/azuremediaplayer.min.js

Comment: Could you only access to this page (https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_setsource.html ) on your devices？Do you try to download this js file and implement on your project?

Comment: Yes initially I tried to implement azure media player on my own website, it didn't work on the mentioned device either.